# if statement OR logic oddity

Tags: java, android

I'm calling this function from a jUnit test case with the following information:

```
// abbr = "US";
// Countries  = array of two objects one with iso2 = "us"
public Country getCountryFromAbbr(String abbr) {
    abbr = abbr.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < Countries.size(); i++) {
        Country country = Countries.get(i);
        String iso2 = country.ISO2.toLowerCase();
        String iso3 = country.ISO3.toLowerCase();

        if (iso2.equals(abbr) || iso3.equals(abbr)) {
            return country;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

When I debug, the second object with `ISO2` of `us` `iso2.equals(abbr)` is true and the other is `false`. However, country is not returned and the debugger finishes the loop and returns `null`.

I'm confused as true || false is true. Am I missing something?

Here's the mock of the countries:

```
    List<Country> Countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
    Country country = new Country();
    country.CountryId = 1;
    country.CountryName = "Great Britian";
    country.ISO2 = "GB";
    country.ISO3 = "GBR";
    Countries.add(country);

    Country usa = new Country();
    usa.CountryId = Studio.USA_COUNTRY_ID;
    usa.CountryName = "United States of America";
    usa.ISO2 = "US";
    usa.ISO3 = "USA";
    Countries.add(usa);
    return Countries;
```

---

EDIT:
I'm using Eclipse and debugging using my Droid X 2.3.3

Comment: you are converting iso2 into lowercase, is your abbr is also in lowercase?

Comment: yeah, `abbr = abbr.toLowerCase()`

Comment: You might try asserting `"us".equals(abbr)`, just to be sure your args are correct.

Comment: How do you know `iso2.equals(abbr)`? Is it what you think is happening or what you know is happening because the debugger told you? I would probably isolate the conditions, and do some watchlisting or asserting or printing: `boolean iso2e = iso2.equals(abbr); console.log(iso2e, iso2, abbr);` and then do the `if` with `iso2e`. That way you can be certain what's actually going on.

Comment: @Amadan, I added iso2.equals(abbr) to a watch variable in the debugger

Comment: It's hard to guess without actually debugging it but.. Is there possibility that content of `Countries` changes after you pass `if` statement ? Multithreading issue maybe ?

Comment: @MikeStewart: I don't trust it. What if you redefined `String.equals` so that it toggles its truth value on alternate calls? :P

Comment: Rarely I found such cases while debugging in Eclipse, when I go step by step, the control goes in wrong place. But, when I check the actual retun value (by printing), then it appears ok. Try `String str = getCountryFromAbbr(...)`, remove all debug break points from inside the getCountryFromAbbr method and then print the str.

Comment: This code works in Java SE 7. I know that `toLowerCase` uses locales to decide what to change each character to, but I can't imagine how that might be screwing up this.

Comment: @MikeStewart: For checking try only with one condition in if like `if(iso2.equals(abbr))` and then `if(iso2.equals(abbr))`. And if it still fails then it might be some issue with encoding/Locales of both strings.

Comment: @Amadan I think if `String.equals` was redefined the OP has enough of a grasp of AOP/byte-code manipulation to figure out that having done so might be the issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I admit that was facetious. I'm just saying there's many reasons I can theoretically think of why a value calculated in a watch dialog and a value calculated again somewhere in the code might have a different value, and that a reliable test would simplify that into just one invocation whose value is cached and reused for actual code and debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work fine with simple if condition?

```
if (iso2.equals(abbr)) {
            return country;
        }
if(iso3.equals(abbr)){
       return country;
}
```

Comment: This helped me figure out what was going on. The debugger was jumping to the `return null` line even though I had a break point on `return country`. Then the statement immediately following `getCountryFromAbbr` was throwing the NullPointerExecption.

Comment: One's comment is another's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for Enum! (whoooooosh!)

```
public enum Country {

    GREAT_BRITAIN("GB", "GBR"),
    USA("US", "USA");

    private String iso2;
    private String iso3;

    private Country(String iso2, String iso3){
        this.iso2 = iso2;
        this.iso3 = iso3;
    }

    public static Country getCountry(String a){
        for (Country c : Country.values()){
            if (c.iso2.equalsIgnoreCase(a) || c.iso3.equalsIgnoreCase(a)){
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null; // no country found!
    }

}
```

If Country is immutable (you're not going to change any values inside it), then this is a neat way of doing it - and you can add id and name as attributes as well. And expose getters if you need access to those attributes.

Your current method accesses `Countries` as an instance variable, instead of as an argument to the method, so it's possible there are side-effects there.

Comment: Well, you might had not got the point. The question is not how to do it, there are plenty of ways to do it. The real question here why the code in the question not working.

Comment: No - I understand the issue. I was just suggesting a working replacement for `getCountryFromAbbr()`. If it doesn't work with _this_ code, then the real issue is actually somewhere else (i.e. in the unit test code).